# File Scanner nosuchelementexception

Tags: java

I have this code (**in** is a file scanner):

```
while(in.hasNext()){
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
        System.out.println(i+", "+j);
        String se = in.next();
        char c = se.charAt(0);
        maze[i][j] = c;
      }
    }
}
```

and every time I run it it ends at 0,49 and then gives me a NoSuchElementException. If I decrease the 50s in the for loops to 49 it stops at 1,0 and throws an exception. What is happening? What am I doing?

Also, if you must know, my file I'm reading is a 50x50 wall of text.

Comment: Exactly what is `in`? Could it potentially be reading a whole line of text into your String `se`?

Comment: @Caleryn in = new Scanner(new File("C://Users//Dragon//Desktop//maze//Maze.txt"));

Comment: @Caleryn Ah yes, it is reading a whole line! How would I make it only read one character?

Comment: consider if `se.charAt(j)` might help...  alternativly, read `nextByte()` and convert it to a character, you may need to worry about character encoding, for the latter.

Comment: @Caleryn I will do something like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your while loop isn't adequately checking if the scanner can actually read the next line. Every call to scanner.next() should be preceded by a call to scanner.hasNext() (to guarantee that the input you are reading actually exists). Your code checks once every 50*50 reads. To fix this, you're going to want to stop the loop if input doesn't exist, either by doing something like

```
while(in.hasNext()){
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
            if(!in.hasNext())
                break;
            System.out.println(i+", "+j);
            String se = in.next();
            char c = se.charAt(0);
            maze[i][j] = c;
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
while(in.hasNext()){
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 50&&in.hasNext(); j++) {
            System.out.println(i+", "+j);
            String se = in.next();
            char c = se.charAt(0);
            maze[i][j] = c;
        }
    }
}
```

which should both check before calling next that input exists, and exit the loop if it doesnt.

Comment: Thanks, but I guess I should have clarified that I'm trying to read one character at a time. I should actually be using a BufferedReader, shouldn't I?

Comment: @user3042719 You could probably use a BufferedReader, although it might be easier to first read the whole file into one big string (using a scanner), then parse that char by char instead.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that! Thanks!